# Module with handle [xxxx] and index [x] has no application entry point

Tags: exception, blackberry

I'm having a problem with calling:

```
HomeScreen.updateIcon(_Icon);
or
HomeScreen.setName("${app.title}");
```

This throws an exception "Module with handle [xxxx] and index [x] has no application entry point". Only when the application is first installed, but not subsequent reboots.

What's wrong with .updateIcon()?

Comment: I added this question with the answer for stackoverlow Google juice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Sohm answers this question wonderfully at [supportforums.blackberry.com](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Alternate-Entry-Point/m-p/82034#M9271) with the resulting answer to:

- Catch the exception,
- Sleep,
- Try updateIcon again.

Reason: "The issue is that the auto start application could run and attempt to set the icon for an entry point that has not been registered with the system (these are happening in parallel)."